# Javascript - Crossfilter - Fetch data from server and find unique users

Tags: javascript, grouping, dimensions, crossfilter

I am a newbie to JS. I know that this question has been asked before - find unique users. What I am unable to get to work is the case when data is being fetched from server. I get a blank screen whenever I try to import data from the server. Here's the .js file :

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "/data2")
.await(makeCharts);

function makeCharts(error, recordsJson) {
//Clean data
var records = recordsJson;
var dateForm = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

records.forEach(function(d) {
    d["timestamp"] = dateForm.parse(d["timestamp"]);
    d["timestamp"].setHours(0,0,0);
});

var ndx = crossfilter(records);
var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["timestamp"]; }); 

var num_unique_ids_by_date = dateDim.group()
    .reduce(
    function (p, d) {
        if(d.userid in p.userids) p.userids[d.userid] ++;
        else{
            p.userids[d.userid] = 1;
            p.id_count++;
        }
        return p;
    },

    function (p, d) {
        p.userids[d.userid]--;
        if(p.userids[d.userid] === 0){
            delete p.userids[d.userid];
            p.id_count--;
        }
        return p;
    },

    function () {
            return {userids: {},
            id_count: 0};
        });

var timeXChart = dc.rowChart("#time-chartX");        

timeXChart
    .width(650)
    .height(140)
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(num_unique_ids_by_date)
    .valueAccessor(function(d){
        return d.value.id_count;
    })
    .elasticX(true) ;      

dc.renderAll();
};
```

Currently I am following this answer - [Crossfilter : find unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239789/crossfilter-reduce-find-number-of-uniques)

This is the sample data in JSON format located at `localhost:8080/data2` :

```
[{"userid":81,"timestamp":"2016-07-29 07:01:37"}, 
{"userid":191,"timestamp":"2016-07-31 07:56:05"}, 
{"userid":36,"timestamp":"2016-08-01 01:44:41"},
{"userid":104,"timestamp":"2016-07-28 05:45:51"}, 
{"userid":184,"timestamp":"2016-08-02 06:22:10"},
{"userid":82,"timestamp":"2016-07-28 05:05:10"},
{"userid":220,"timestamp":"2016-08-05 06:39:19"},
{"userid":16,"timestamp":"2016-06-04 03:44:40"},
{"userid":16,"timestamp":"2016-06-04 03:48:29"},
{"userid":16,"timestamp":"2016-06-04 03:48:54"},
{"userid":16,"timestamp":"2016-06-04 03:50:09"},
{"userid":16,"timestamp":"2016-06-04 06:14:34"}];
```

This is the error log -

`Error: <rect> attribute height: A negative value is not valid. ("-4.269230769230769")`

Comment: Usually this happens when something goes wrong in your group. Can you either put together a working example, or show what the full output of `num_unique_ids_by_date.all()` looks like?